# Como inserir via SQLite um dado na sua respective Acitivity

Tags: java, android, sqlite

Pessoal estou fazendo um aplicativo em android e dentro dele tem uma `listiView` fixa enviada por um array de string por exemplo

```
 String[] servicos = {"Eletricista", "Pedreiro", "Pintor", "Encanador", "Arquiteto", "Engenheiro", "Marcineiro", "Serralheiro"};
```

Na minha aplicação gostaria que o usuário que trabalhasse dentro da sua respectiva área se cadastrasse e fosse adicionado dentro da sua área, já possuo o formulário pronto

exemplo da situação -> um eletricista se cadastra e seu nome é jogado direto na `Activity` do eletricista.

Como faço para o `sqlite` pegue os dados e jogue dentro da sua respectiva `Activity`.

O projeto é do curso .
Peço desculpa se falei besteira sou iniciante no `android`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

faz varios `else if` ou `switch case` que o mandaram para sua respectiva activity, neste exemplo suponho que o cadastro esteja sendo feito na `MainActivity`:

```
Intent it;
switch(tipo) {
    case "encanador": 
        it = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Encanador.class);
        startActivity(it);
        break;
    case "eletricista":
        it = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Eletricista.class);
        startActivity(it);
        break;
}
```

Serve?

Sei que existe a possibilidade de usar um `Class.forName(tipo)` em vez de usar `Classe.class`, sendo tipo uma `String`, porém não sei usar

**Edit:**

Complementando com a resposta do @ramaral:

```
try {
    Class classe = Class.forName("nome.do.pacote." + classe);
    startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, classe));
} catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Sendo `classe` a variável cadastrada no banco

Lembrando que o nome das classes devem ser iguais as cadastradas

Comment: Para utilizar `Class.forName(tipo)` faça assim: `try {Class classe = Class.forName("NomeDaPackage.NomeDaActiviy");startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, classe));} catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {e.printStackTrace();}`. No entanto, para evitar o `switch/case`, o array terá de ter o nome da classe da activity correspondente.

Comment: Resposta complementada, não funcionava comigo porque não colocava o nome do pacote também

Comment: Se a pergunta foi sanada, feche-a, senão exponha suas dúvidas por favor